# ActionController::UnknownFormat when try to add .js file to my rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am trying to get some .js on my rails app and I have 1 problem.

There is already one same question, but answer is not good for me also.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body))
    @comment.name = current_user.email
    respond_to do |format|
        if @comment.save
            format.js 
            redirect_to article_path(@article)
        else
        end
    end
end

def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
end

end
```

There is also Create.js.erb file

```
$('#forma2 table').append("<%= j render @comment %>")
```

And error from terminal

```
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/articles/90
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 27ms (ActiveRecord: 10.5ms)



ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):

app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR Remove the redirect after format.js

You can't respond with JS and then redirect.
Redirects are for HTTP requests. Removing the redirect should fix your issue.
If you want to handle HTTP requests as well then add `format.html` before the redirect.

If you want to redirect you can pass in the redirect URL into your JS and from there manipulate URL with window.location or something.